# Implicit and explicit differentiation give contradictory answers in related rates problem.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, related-rates

The problem statement:

> Oil spreads on a frying pan so that it's radius is proportional to
>   $t^{1/2}$, where $t$ represents the time from the moment when the oil
>   is poured. Find the change $dT/dt$ of the thickness T of the oil.

From the solution I can tell that we should assume that the oil is in the shape of a cylinder and that the volume is constant.

Implicit solution (according to textbook):

$r = kt^{1/2}$

$r^2T = \frac{V}{\pi} = c$ (definition of the volume of a cylinder)

$2r\frac{dr}{dt}T + r^2\frac{dT}{dt} = 0$

$\frac{dT}{dt} = -\frac{2}{r}\frac{dr}{dt}$

$\frac{dT}{dt} = -\frac{1}{t}$ (after computing the derivative of r)

According to the textbook this is the correct solution, but if we differentiate explicitly:

$r = kt^{1/2}$

$T = \frac{V}{r^2\pi} = \frac{V}{k^2t\pi}$

$\frac{dT}{dt} = -\frac{V}{k^2\pi} \frac{1}{t^2} = -\frac{r^2\pi T}{k^2\pi} \frac{1}{t^2} = -\frac{k^2tT}{k^2} \frac{1}{t^2} = -\frac{T}{t}$

If both of the solution are correct then $\frac{dT}{dt} = -\frac{1}{t} = -\frac{T}{t}$ and $T = 1$, which can't be possible. Why does differentiating implicitly and explicitly give different contradictory solutions?

Comment: check your algebra again, you should get $\frac{dT}{dt} = -\frac{2T}{r}\frac{dr}{dt}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you move from the third to the fourth line in the book solution, you drop a factor of $T$. The fourth line should read $\frac{dT}{dt}=-\frac{2T}{r}\frac{dr}{dt}$.

Comment: Ah I see. That T is also dropped in the in the textbook. Below the solution is says "Although we only know the rate of change of r up to a constant of proportionality we can compute the absolute rate of change of T" Is that also incorrect then? And is my explicit solution valid?

Comment: Your explicit solution looks valid to me. The statement in the textbook below the solution is correct; it's basically just saying that the final rate of change you compute doesn't depend on $k$, only on $T$ and $t$.

Comment: But if T depends on k, and it does, then doesn't that make the aforementioned statement false?

Comment: $T$ does depend on $k$, but if you know $T$ and $t$, you don't need to know $k$ to get $\frac{dT}{dt}$. (This is a nontrivial statement, because $T$ *also* depends on the unknown constant $V$, so knowing $T$ and $t$ isn't enough information to determine $k$.)